# Proof by using Archimedes property

Tags: real-analysis

I have been given this exercise:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that there exists $C \in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ we have $x \leq {C}/{n}$. Use Archimedes property to show that $x\leq 0$.

I know that Archimedes property is given by: For $x,y>0$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{n}$ such that $nx>y$.

My attempt:
For $x, C>0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx>C$ $\leftrightarrow x>{C}/{n}$, but $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} C/n = 0$, so eventually $C/n$ gets smaller than any positive number when n goes to $\infty$. From this we must have that $x\leq 0$ because the argument must hold for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I´m very new at real analysis, so I don´t know what I can assume and where to start.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Interesting question. What have you tried? What issues are you facing to prove the requested result?

Comment: @AnotherUser thanks for letting me know. I will edit the question.

Comment: @AnotherUser is it better now?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I edit the question, so you can see what I think.

Comment: The point is to use the Archimedean property to show that $\frac Cn$ eventually gets smaller than any positive number.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $x \leq 0$. Well, what happens if $x>0$? If that’s the case, then by the Archimedean property there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $nx>C$ (we cannot say this if $x$ is not greater than zero), and so $x>C/n$.

That is, if we assume that $x>0$, then the condition
$$
\forall n \in \Bbb N \quad x \leq C/n
$$
doesn’t hold. In other words, if the above condition holds, then $x \leq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! So helpful. I saw that I was almost there.